# May they rest in peace

Tags: idiom, english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation, conjugation

This may become an inscription written on a historical marker commemorating a mass grave.  Which of the following is correct:  *Requiesce in Pace* or *Requiescant in Pace*?  The former was offered up by a young lady who was in my high school Latin class 50 years ago.  The second was provided by translate.google.com.  I think we are looking for third person, plural, subjunctive, present tense.  I have seen google's form on a photograph of a slate grave marker dated 1725, but, the stone didn't have almost 300 years of patina on it.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for your question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Requiescant in pace** is what you are looking for. Just as you say, third person, plural, subjunctive, present tense form, *may they rest in peace*.

(*Requiesce in pace*, instead, is singular, imperative mood, so the sentence is commanding someone to rest in peace, or figuratively, wishing it.)

Both the plural and singular (**requiescat in pace**) forms have traditionally been part of Christian prayers for the dead. Here a prominent example in Catholic liturgy, the *[Requiem](http://www.preces-latinae.org/thesaurus/Varia/Requiem.html)*, which is part of the *Missa pro defunctis*:

> Requiem aeternam dona ei(eis), Domine, et lux perpetua luceat ei(eis). Requiescat(-ant) in pace. Amen.
>   *Eternal rest grant unto him/her (them), O Lord, and let perpetual light shine upon him/her (them). May he/she (they) rest in peace. Amen.*