# What would be the appropriate translation for "Dedicated to my father, may he rest in peace"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, sentence-translation

I have a translation question. Normally, I would use Google, but I am hoping immortalize it in my M.S. thesis, so I wanted to be sure about the correct translation for "Dedicated to my father, may he rest in peace." or, if it sounds more appropriate in Latin, "For my father, may he rest in peace."

Following the guideline found [here](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/483/how-can-i-ask-a-translation-question-if-i-dont-know-any-latin):

> Where is the text from?

Something I came up with myself, though I imagine others have before me as well.

> What do you exactly want to convey with the text? and What would the
> text be used for?

Dedicating my M.S. thesis to my father in the opening pages. As a sign of gratitude and respect.

> What have you done to translate the text yourself?

I checked this [website](https://latindiscussion.org/threads/dear-daddy-rest-in-peace.16075/) and this [answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12680/may-they-rest-in-peace) that offered something similar, and used Google.

> If you have a suggested translation, where is it from?

Using the above 3 sources, I think this would be somewhat correct:

*Dedicated to my father, may he rest in peace.*: Dicata patri meo, Requiescat in pace.

*For my father, may he rest in peace.*: Nam pater meus sit in pace.

I hope this might be enough information to make answering this question easy. Please let me know if anything else is required. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Would that all translation requests were so reasonable and diligent!

Comment: I am not sure if I am allowed to comment such things, if not, it can be deleted: Thank you very much! I just didn't want to take too much of the experts' time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No problem with “Requiescat in pace”. For “dedicated to NN” the usual expression is just NN in the dative case, so in this instance “patri meo” or simply “patri”. If you want something less Christian and more classical you could say “dis manibus patris”, or abbreviated to D M Patris, “to the immortal spirits of (my) father”.  Or less abrupt: “Patri carissimo”: “To (my) dearest father”.

Comment: To be pedantically clear (apologies), I can go with "Patri carissimo. Requiescat in pace." correct? Thank you very much!

Comment: @KindDude. you can.

Comment: Ok, thank you again!